# Summary of search results does not display --> properly, omits the >

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

[Consider this query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:772868%20%5Bdcg%5D%20seq). What is shown as

```
seq([]) -- [].
```

should actually be

```
seq([]) --> [].
```

This happens, if `-->` occurs within markdown formatted programs. If the program text is formatted with `<pre>`, the `-->` is properly displayed in the results. Below is part of the search-result. The first (answered jun 29'11) shows a `--` while the second (answered mar 20) shows the expected `-->`, but this time `<pre>` is used (for highlighting in a transcript).

[image: Red: bad; Green: good.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This required a full re-indexing of the network...so that was fun to get working right.

Anyway, search results should display all HTML entities correctly now, enjoy!

Comment: That was fast! Thank you!